# The "hyphen" dictation command inserts en-dash instead

Tags: macos, voice-dictation

The help article [Commands for dictating text on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/commands-for-dictating-text-on-mac-mh40695/mac) state that if we say "hyphen", it should be the hyphen character (U+002D), but instead it places the en dash (U+2013). I remember this on Ventura and I have the same on Sonoma. Is it a bug?

**Do you have the same issue on your Mac?**

Comment: U+002D is actually 'hyphen-minus' `-`, which is the general-purpose one your keyboard would naturally generate. True hyphen `‐` is U+2010 [but that's just me being picky;)